# A self-contained example showing how Gitlab CI's "parallel" works

Tags: python

Here's the code:

```
"""A proof of concept that shows how to use Gitlab CI's "parallel" keyword
in order to parallelize a large battery of unit tests across many nodes.

In order to give it a try, create a test project with more than one job
available and create a .gitlab-ci.yml file with the following contents:

    test:
    image: python:3.10
    script: python3 main.py
    parallel: 2

"""

import unittest
import time
import hashlib
import os
import logging

# This one is here for type annotations. Only used in string type, thus not
# caught by pylint:
import typing  # pylint: disable=unused-import


# "Import" environment variables from Gitlab CI. If not set, default to
# a single node, resulting in no speedups when run on a local machine.
CI_NODE_INDEX = int(os.environ.get("CI_NODE_INDEX", 1))
CI_NODE_TOTAL = int(os.environ.get("CI_NODE_TOTAL", 1))


class ParallelTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """
    Allows you to take advantage of Gitlab CI's "parallel" functionality.

    You can use it to parallelize a large battery of unit tests by spreading
    them across multiple CI nodes.

    Use in place of unittest.TestCase as a base class.
    """

    @classmethod
    def willRunInOtherStage(
        cls: "typing.Type[ParallelTestCase]", func_name: str
    ) -> bool:
        """Takes a function name and decides whether it will run on the
        current node."""
        # we need a deterministic hash function, so unfortunately hash()
        # won't do:
        hashed_func_name_as_int = int(
            hashlib.md5(func_name.encode()).hexdigest().upper(), 16
        )
        # +1, because CI_NODE variables are 1-indexed.
        should_run_on_node = (hashed_func_name_as_int % CI_NODE_TOTAL) + 1
        logging.debug(
            "willRunInOtherStage(%r)=%r", func_name, should_run_on_node
        )
        return should_run_on_node == CI_NODE_INDEX

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls: "typing.Type[ParallelTestCase]") -> None:
        """Finds all test_ methods and makes sure that the ones that should
        run on another node will be skipped."""
        if cls is ParallelTestCase:
            raise RuntimeError("Should not be executed directly")
        super(ParallelTestCase, cls).setUpClass()
        for key in cls.__dict__:
            if not key.startswith("test_"):
                continue
            # in order to avoid name collisions resulting in wasted CPU cycles,
            # let's also include module and class names
            full_test_name = f"{__name__}.{cls.__name__}.{key}"
            should_it_skip = cls.willRunInOtherStage(full_test_name)

            orig_fn = getattr(cls, key)
            decorated_function = unittest.skipIf(
                should_it_skip, "will run on another CI node"
            )(orig_fn)
            setattr(cls, key, decorated_function)


class ExampleTestCase(ParallelTestCase):
    """An example time-intensive test case. We define two tests in order to
    display parallelization at work."""
    # pylint: disable=no-self-use,missing-function-docstring
    def test_first(self) -> None:
        time.sleep(120.0)

    def test_second(self) -> None:
        time.sleep(120.0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level="DEBUG")
    unittest.main()
```

As an exercise, I put in maximum effort into making it readable. Is there something else that could be improved?